# Как переписать код, заменив цикл for на метод forEach?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
const a = [
  'Гарри Поттер и философский камень',
  'Гарри Поттер и Тайная комната',
  'Гарри Поттер и узник Азкабана',
  'Гарри Поттер и Кубок огня',
  'Гарри Поттер и Орден феникса',
  'Гарри Поттер и Принц-полукровка',
  'Гарри Поттер и Дары смерти',
  'Гарри Поттер и методы рационального мышления',
];
const b = [];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b.push(a[i].split(' и ')[1]); // Перепишите a[i] на переменную из метода forEach
}
console.log(b);
```

Как переписать код, заменив цикл for на метод forEach?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [
  'Гарри Поттер и философский камень',
  'Гарри Поттер и Тайная комната',
  'Гарри Поттер и узник Азкабана',
  'Гарри Поттер и Кубок огня',
  'Гарри Поттер и Орден феникса',
  'Гарри Поттер и Принц-полукровка',
  'Гарри Поттер и Дары смерти',
  'Гарри Поттер и методы рационального мышления',
];

const b = [];
a.forEach(function (item) {
  b.push(item.split(' и ')[1]); // Перепишите a[i] на переменную из метода forEach
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score -2):

`forEach` -- метод массивов, который применяет какие-то операции к каждому элементу массива. На вход ему подается колбэк функция, в которую передаются три аргумента: текущее значение из массива, его индекс и массив, по которому осуществляется проход. Последние два необязательные.

Значит нужно вместо вашего `for(...)` подставить `a.forEach(...)`, в который необходимо передать колбэк с аргументом `item`, который будет выступать в роли текущего элемента массива `item => {...}`, а внутри подставить строку из вашего цикла, заменив `a[i]` на `item`

Пример:

```js
const a = [
  'Гарри Поттер и философский камень',
  'Гарри Поттер и Тайная комната',
  'Гарри Поттер и узник Азкабана',
  'Гарри Поттер и Кубок огня',
  'Гарри Поттер и Орден феникса',
  'Гарри Поттер и Принц-полукровка',
  'Гарри Поттер и Дары смерти',
  'Гарри Поттер и методы рационального мышления',
];
const b = [];

a.forEach(item => {
   b.push(item.split(' и ')[1]);
}) 

console.log(b);
```